# Not receiving post data in Codeigniter AJAX form

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, csrf

I'm trying to achieve posting a newsletter form to Codeigniter by an AJAX request.
I'm using CSRF protection.
I have the following code and I can't seem to get the posted values and thus not the response properly back. 
Several different things happen:

1. If I have name="email" in the input field, the CSRF fails and I get 500 (Internal Server Error)
2. If I leave it out, then I get the below printed to the console meaning that it does go to controller but doesn't fetch post values. (undefined is the response on the ajax() function

   undefined

   Object {status: "error", message: "Please fill in a correct email address", email: " Email: "}
3. If I keep the name="email" and do console.log(data) in the top of ajax() then I get the values as different objects, like this

   [Object],[Object]

   Object name: "csrf_test_name" value: "e31943d629f0a47d449f21997c220446"

   Object name: "email" value: "my@email.com"

I'm trying to have the form and AJAX request in different functions in order to only write the form handler again when I make new forms.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong? I believe there is something with the formats when serializing that I don't understand. Currently I only log to console because I'm lost in where the errors are.

HTML

```
<form role="form" id="subscriber_form">
    <input id="csrf" type="hidden" name="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>" value="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>"/>
    <div class="alert hidden" id="returnmessage">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-group-default input-group">
       <label>Email address</label>
       <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="name@company.com" required />
    </div>
    <button id="subscribe_submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" type="button">Subscribe!</button>
</form>
```

Javascript (JQuery 1.11.1)

```
function ajaxSubmit(form,url,data){
    console.log(data);
   $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: data,
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);

    }
  });
}

$('#subscribe_submit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var form = '#subscriber_form';
    var url = 'subscribers/save_subscriber';
    var data = $(form).serializeArray();

    var response = ajaxSubmit(form, url, data);

    console.log(response)
});
```

PHP (Codeigniter 3.0)

```
function save_subscriber(){

    $data = array(
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),            
        'created' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    );

    $success_response = array(
        'status' => 'success',
        'message'=> 'You now subscribe to our newsletter'
    );
    $error_response = array(
        'status' => 'error',
        'message'=> 'Please fill in a correct email address',
        'email' => " Email: ". $data['email']
    );
     $valid_email = validate_email($data['email']);
     if ($data['email'] != "" && $valid_email == TRUE) {        
        $this->_insert($data);
        $response = $success_response;
    }
    else{
        $response = $error_response;
    }
    echo json_encode($response);

}
```

Furthermore I tried to set it up with ajaxSetup and JQuery cookie, but with no success as I can't get the data into the function. I thought it was global.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
     data: {
         "csrf_test_name": $.cookie('csrf_cookie_name')
     }
});
```

**EDIT**
I have solved this partially. I turned on logging

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 2;
```

and found that I had an error in a model that I copied from CI 2.0. This solved the problem of getting post values.

**ELABORATION**
I also realized that I cannot do what I explained with the AJAX requests above, because that would either make the request not asynchronous or stall the browser while waiting for a response.

Comment: Where is url define ?? show that

Comment: URL is defined in the form handler var url = 'subscribers/save_subscriber'; If I remove the `name="email"` from form then I get this response back without any server errors. `Object {status: "error", message: "Please fill in a correct email address", email: " Email: "}` It just does not receive the post values in the controller.

Comment: without `base_url`  you cant call the site path

Comment: It does find the right controller even in the console when it displays the server error 500. If I add full path then it doesn't help.

Comment: You're echoing JSON without modifying the content-type header. I would suggest using `$this->output->set_content_type('application/json')` before outputting anything. I would also suggest using `$this->output->set_output()` instead of echo to avoid header issues.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using:

```
var data = $(form).serializeArray();
```

Use

```
var data = $(form).serialize();
```

The method `serialize()` generates proper form encoding that is received by `$_POST` or `$_GET`

`serializeArray()` creates completely different structure like:

```
[
  {
    name: "email",
    value: "1"
  },
  {
    name: "password",
    value: "2"
  }
]
```

Comment: The choice of `serialize` vs `serializeArray` is not the answer. The choice does not affect the outcome **in any way**. In fact, if you look at the jQuery source code you will see that the first thing `serialize()` does is call `serializeArray()`.

Comment: @DFriend you are entitled to your opinion , however the array would then have to be looped through to access each `name/value` instead of automatically having name available as keys of $_POST or $_GET. `serialze()` encodes the data the extra step to send the data in the exact same format that default browser submit process does. Also note that `serilalizeArray()` requires recursively restructuring all names that are set as array notation in the form controls themselves

Comment: here is the entire source code for `serialize` from jquery.js `serialize: function() { return jQuery.param( this.serializeArray() );  },`  The function `jQuery.param` actually does the work of creating the query string. If you look into the source code of the `ajax` function you will find that it calls `jQuery.param` if `data` isn't a already a string. So,the choice of `serialize` or `serialzeArray`to obtain `data` makes no difference. Either way, correctly formatted data will be sent to the server. Your answer has no bearing on the outcome.

Comment: @DFriend it sure does if OP isn't expecting data in different structure than default form post would produce. I know how $.param works and it basically simplifies the need fr having to do the transform at server. OP can't access the `name` in input using `$_POST['name']` without doing that transform server side if data sent as `serlializeArray()`

Comment: I'm probably being dense but define OP.

Comment: @DFriend  *"Original Post[er]"*  .. universally accepted abbreviation in this site

Comment: But my point is that both serialization methods result in the same data (in the same format) being sent to the server. Each produces exactly the same `$_POST` array at the server. With the exception of the submit button they produce the same results as a 'normal' form posting.

Comment: @DFriend no they don't. That's like saying their is no point to have method `serialize()`

Comment: They do. Try it for yourself. 

Either function might find purpose in something other than posting a form. (Not that I can think of one at the moment.) `serializeArray()` allows easy access to - and manipulation of - input data prior to posting. That's often be useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been solved. The answer was not directly related to the problem. I turned on logging in Codeigniter and found errors elsewhere, that didn't show. Thanks for your help.